# Remove Button Padding ASP/HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, button, padding

I'm trying to get absolute 0 padding around my button.

[image: Button]

I have tried

```
padding:0px;
```

But as you can see from the image I still have space top and bottom of the button (Blue line is border). Any suggestions?

Edit: Button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="WPDErrorBtn" Style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:65px; background:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; border:none; " runat="server" OnClick="WPDErrorBtn_Click" OnClientClick="showLoading();" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the line-height to for example 65px; the chances are real that you have to try a smaller number.

**Edit example**

```html
<button style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:65px; background:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; border:1px solid blue; line-height:50px;">0</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked, I was never aware of line-height.

Answer (score 0):

What is this inside border, number or picture?
try this ---> padding:0px !important;
But i think it is not padding issue, please more details...